# angular material module not found after importing new modules

Tags: angular, npm, angular-material, npm-install, angular-module

In **angular** when i am **importing a new material module** it throws error:

```
ERROR in ./src/app/app.component.ngfactory.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '@angular/material/core/index' in 'C:\Users\hrshcse\angularmat\src\app'
```

The import statements are correct, and i need to do:

```
npm install @angular/material
```

or

```
npm install --save @angular/material
```

Each time to solve this error.

Answer (score 0):

There is an update angular material. 
If you want to import any module,
it should be done as

```
import { MatButtonModule} from '@angular/material/buttons'
import { MatInputModule} from '@angular/material/input'
```

Comment: yeah, import statements are defined correctly but the problem is i need to run npm install every time

Comment: run npm install globally and restart the app.

Comment: import{MatMenuModule} from '@angular/material/menu'

Comment: please upload your project in stackblitz and share me the link